# Comma confusion in this sentence

Tags: commas

> This of course wasn't the only functionality that came with iCloud, but regardless, developers weren't exactly enthusiastic.

or

> This of course wasn't the only functionality that came with iCloud, but, regardless, developers weren't exactly enthusiastic.

Are both correct?

Comment: "This of course wasn't the only functionality that came with iCloud but, regardless, developers weren't exactly enthusiastic." Because "regardless" is a parenthesis and there is no comma needed except to set it apart from the main sentence.

Comment: @MetaEd  Replacing 'regardless' by the more natural-sounding 'nevertheless', I'd say that  _This of course wasn't the only functionality that came with iCloud, but nevertheless, developers weren't exactly enthusiastic._ is arguably acceptable to echo how one would read this. I've certainly come across a recommendation that zero punctuation be considered on certain occasions for parentheticals, and this might seem a further sensible stretching of the rules.

Comment: @MetaEd Interesting, because there is no way I would ever do it that way. The break before *but* is the more important one, and if I was going to set the parenthetical off with a comma after *but*, I would use a semicolon before *but*. But I would normally do as in OP's first example.

Answer (score 1):

No, both aren't **correct** (a generally meaningless term when applied to punctuation: only **incorrect** works), but they're both **acceptable** to someone or other. What's *correct* here depends on who's making the judgment. Comma rules are amoebic and amorphous. They vary with the writer, the editor, the style manual, and the linguist/grammarian/English teacher who looks at the sentence.

> This, of course, wasn't the only functionality that came with iCloud, but, regardless, developers weren't exactly enthusiastic.  [OK]
>   This of course wasn't the only functionality that came with iCloud, but, regardless, developers weren't exactly enthusiastic.  [OK]
>   This, of course, wasn't the only functionality that came with iCloud; however, developers weren't exactly enthusiastic.  [OK and better]
>   This of course wasn't the only functionality that came with iCloud; however, developers weren't exactly enthusiastic.  [OK and better]

See [this](http://www.informatics.sussex.ac.uk/department/docs/punctuation/node00.html) for so-called *comma rules*. Not everything is clear, but it's a generally very good analysis of how to use commas. Don't take the names of the comma types seriously unless you want to be confused. Just look at how Trask uses them and what he says is **proper** use.

Comment: I think your claim that “comma rules are [amoebic](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/amoebic)” (ie, relating to, or caused by an [amoeba](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/amoeba)) is incorrect.

Comment: @jwpat7: Why? They make as much sense as the world's #1 amoebically induced condition: [amoebic dysentery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amoebic_dysentery), & the end result (pardon the pun) is olfactorily and structurally isomorphic writing, IMHO. :-)

Comment: +1 Beautiful answer. @jwpat7 You are viewing this use of "amoebic" in an exceedingly narrow and very literal interpretation. One of the wonderful things about English, however, is the potential to use words in creative ways, and Bill Franke has come up with a colorful, inventive use of the term "amoebic" here. Think of how amoebae exhibit continuously and elusively mutating shapes, and you'll get an idea of what Bill means with regard to comma rules.

Comment: @JohnM.: Thank you, John. Just so. As Lakoff and Johnson's title says, _[Metaphors We Live By](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conceptual_metaphor)_.

Comment: ... But only some amoebas are life-enhancing (probably the ones who prefer to be called amoebae aren't).

Comment: @jwpat7  'pertaining to _or resembling_ amoebae [in some respect]' ([vocabulary.com/dictionary](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/amoebic)), and doubtless in OED. If we're not careful, we'll be into _Isn't 'better' incorrect? 'a gambler', the dictionary says._

Comment: I'm suffering from amoebic disinterest!